# DevExpress LookUpEdit Column Binding To Navigation Property

Tags: winforms, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

Good day!
I'm having an issue with the DevExpress LookUpEdit I can't figure out what the problem is.
I'm use Entity Framework list as a datasource.

```
    public partial class provider_scheme : BaseEntity
{
    public provider_scheme()
    {
    }

    public int Provider_Scheme_RowID { get; set; }
    public int Currency_RowID { get; set; }
    public string Provider_Scheme_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual currency currency { get; set; }
}

public partial class currency : BaseEntity
{
    public currency()
    {
        provider_scheme = new HashSet<provider_scheme>();
    }

    public int Currency_RowID { get; set; }
    public string Currency_ISOCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<provider_scheme> provider_scheme { get; set; }
}
```

I'm setting the Datasource property of the LookUpEdit to IEnumerable<provider_scheme>, and setting up two column field names in my LookUpEdit. One for 'Provider_Scheme_Name' and one for 'currency.Currency_ISOCode'. But for some reason only the 'Provider_Scheme_Name' column values are showing. I've also checked and the 'currency' navigation property is being loaded.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for an answer, but you might consider using the GridLookupEdit control instead. It permits adding all the columns you want